# If $Z$ is a subspace of $Y$ and if $f: X \to Z$ is continuous, then $g: X \to Y$ defined by $g(x) = f(x)$, for every $x \in X$, is also continuous.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Show that if $Z$ is a subspace of $Y$ and if $f: X \to Z$ is continuous, then $g: X \to Y$ defined by $g(x) = f(x)$, for every $x \in X$, is also continuous.

My idea: I want to use the property that for every open set $U$ in $Z$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

The solution says $g(X)\subset Z$. But why is this true? Then it follows that $g^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(U \cap Z)$, which I don't understand how they got either.

Comment: $g(X)$ is the same set of points as $f(X)$, and $f(X)$ is a subset of $Z$.

Comment: Oh, because they are defined to have equal output...I see now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in X$, then $g(x)=f(x)\in Z$, since $f$ is a map from $X$ to $Z$. Therefore, $g(X)\subset Z$.

And, if $x\in X$,\begin{align}x\in g^{-i}(U)&\iff g(x)\in U\\&\iff f(x)\in U\\&\iff f(x)\in U\cap Z,\end{align}since, again, $f$ is a map from $X$ to $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h:Z \to Y$ be the natural injection from $Z$ to $Y$, defined by $h(z) = z$ for all $z \in Z$. If $U$ is an open subset of $Y$, then $h^{-1}(U) = U \cap Z$ is an open subset of $Z$, by definition of the topology on a subspace. Thus $h$ is continuous. Since $g = h \circ f$, $g$ is the composition of two continuous maps, and hence is also continuous.